# Array of Object Model

Tags: django, django-models

I'm beginner with Django and I have problem to register model array of object from another class

Example:

```
class Trigger(models.Model):
   id = models.IntegerField()
   name = models.TextField()
   description = models.TextField()


class Host(models.Model):
   id = models.IntegerField()
   triggers = [] # <--- Array of Trigger instances here
```

How can I rewrite empty bracets to django model?

Comment: can a trigger belong to multiple hosts?

Comment: One trigger (instance) can belong only to one host.

Answer (score 1):

You usually do that by adding a [**`ForeignKey`** [django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) to a trigger that references to the `Host`, and then use as `related_name=` here `'triggers`':

```
class Host(models.Model):
   id = models.IntegerField()

class Trigger(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.TextField()
    description = models.TextField()
    host = ForeignKey(Host, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='triggers')
```

Django will that add a reverse relation to `Host`. So you can then query `somehost.triggers`, which is a `RelatedManager`, to for example obtain `.all()`, elements, or `.filter(..)` these. So `somehost.triggers.all()` will result in a `QuerySet` that contains *all* `Trigger` objects with as `host` the `somehost` instance.